# Is there a way to line wrap org-mode source blocks when exporting?

Tags: org-mode, wrapping

In an org-mode document, I sometimes have markdown source blocks, like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC markdown
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
#+END_SRC
```

**Problem:** When exporting to HTML & opening, these markdown blocks don't line wrap, so all of the text is cut off/not visible (instead it just displays on one huge line, as above).

**Question:** Is there a way to instruct org-mode to line wrap markdown source blocks?